# Material UI Adding Custom Color in Theme Not Recognized

Tags: reactjs, colors, material-ui, themes

I am trying to create a custom theme with custom colors using Material UI in React. When I create the custom theme and view it in the console, I can see the new color with its value. But when I try to reference it in a component, in my case a Switch, I get the following error

index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `color` of value `neutral` supplied to `ForwardRef(Switch)`, expected one of ["default","primary","secondary"]

When I set the color to "primary" or "secondary", I get the expected color. It just seems to not allow for the new color I created.

Here is my theme:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: "#33d9b2"
        },
        secondary: {
            main: "#40407a"
        },
        neutral: {
            main: "#ff793f"
        }
    }
});

export default customTheme;
```

Here is my Switch component:

```
<FormGroup>
   <FormControlLabel
        control={<Switch color="neutral" checked={this.props.isChecked} onChange={this.handleToggleChecked} />}
        label="2018 Tracks">
   </FormControlLabel>
</FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, according to [Material UI Switch docs](https://material-ui.com/api/switch/), `color` prop accepts only `default`, `primary` or `secondary` values.

If you want to make a switch with your `neutral` color, you have to make a custom switch. Something like:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
...
const NeutralSwitch = withStyles({
    switchBase: {
        color: "#808080",  //grey if unchecked
        '&$checked': {
            color: "#ff793f",   //neutral color
        },
        '&$checked + $track': {
            backgroundColor: "#ff793f",   //neutral color
        },
    },
    checked: {},
    track: {},
})(Switch);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch @Giovanni! I was looking at this in the docs: https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors and wouldn't have thought that some components wouldn't allow you to use new colors.

Comment: No problem @sgrozz. I faced the same issue some time ago and I solved with a custom item. Custom colors are useful but only if you use them in css and not to color a component (even if would be very cool if material ui made this functionality :) )

Answer (score 0):

The latest Material UI V5, they have custom color support as you expected. So we could add custom values, both for the palettes on the theme and the colors. You can read the documentation here: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors.

If you read a little further below, it has Typescript support too. The idea is, to declare and override the existing Material UI interfaces.

I have created Codesandbox demo in typescript: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-engelbart-hnimgm?file=/src/App.tsx.

The main work is living at `/src/theme.ts`. As you can see, the `customTheme` part is really exactly what you have already.

But if you are interested in using Typescript, you should consider next to block:

```
...


// allow configuration using `createTheme`
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface PaletteOptions {
    neutral?: PaletteOptions["primary"];
  }
}

// Update the Button's color prop options
declare module "@mui/material/Button" {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    neutral: true;
  }
}

// Update the Switch's color prop options
declare module "@mui/material/Switch" {
  interface SwitchPropsColorOverrides {
    neutral: true;
  }
}

...
```

If you not using Typescript, I guess what you have done is enough. Just declare the "Theme options" like that. I never tried without Typescript though.

Following is the full code of `src/theme.ts` for future reference in this answer:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

// A custom theme for this app

const customTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#33d9b2"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#40407a"
    },
    neutral: {
      main: "#ff793f"
    }
  }
});

// allow configuration using `createTheme`
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface PaletteOptions {
    neutral?: PaletteOptions["primary"];
  }
}

// Update the Button's color prop options
declare module "@mui/material/Button" {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    neutral: true;
  }
}

// Update the Switch's color prop options
declare module "@mui/material/Switch" {
  interface SwitchPropsColorOverrides {
    neutral: true;
  }
}

export default customTheme;
```

Comment: This isn't an answer.